# Getting name of subtype field in feature class in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, subtype

I have a geodatabase with many feature classes. Some of the feature classes have subtype fields. Their names vary feature class by feature class. I now want to find the names of those subtype fields. 
What I have so far is:

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","",dataset):
    subtypefields = arcpy.da.ListSubtypes(fc)
    for subtype in subtypefields:
```

Now, I don't know how to continue from here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [a good example in the documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000021000000). Adapted for your purposes:

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","",dataset):
    subtypes = arcpy.da.ListSubtypes(fc)
    for stcode, stdict in subtypes.iteritems():
        print('Code: {0}'.format(stcode))
        for stkey in stdict.iterkeys():
            if stkey == 'FieldValues':
                print('Fields:')
                fields = stdict[stkey]
                for field, fieldvals in fields.iteritems():                
                    print(' --Field name: {0}'.format(field))
                    print(' --Field default value: {0}'.format(fieldvals[0]))
                    if not fieldvals[1] is None:
                        print(' --Domain name: {0}'.format(fieldvals[1].name))
            else:                    
                print('{0}: {1}'.format(stkey, stdict[stkey]))
```